# Android: getting Null Pointer Exception when inserting in Array

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the error ***"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array"*** when, after getting some data from database I have to put that data in a ArrayAdapter.

```
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());

        List <Gasto> gastos;
        gastos = databaseHelper.getAllGastos();

        Gasto[] items=null;

        for(int i=0;i<gastos.size();i++)
        {
            items[i] = new Gasto(gastos.get(i).getMes(),gastos.get(i).getAno(), gastos.get(i).getDespesa_final());

        }

dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Gasto>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
```

Can you please tell me how can I solve this error?

Comment: You have this line of code _"Gasto[] items = null;"_ which surely causes a NPE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Gasto[] items=null;
```

you have to create the array of `Gastos` before accessing it:

```
Gasto[] items = new Gastos[gastos.size()];
```

Comment: I do know it, but if I do what you said, I can't do this "items[i] = new Gasto(gastos.get(i).getMes(),gastos.get(i).getAno(), gastos.get(i).getDespesa_final());"

Comment: why you can't? What I wrote allocates memory for the array. what you wrote create the object you want to store into the array. Both are needed.

Answer (score 2):

`Gasto[] items = null;` is the problem. Array is not created when you insert to it. Use `Gasto[] items = new Gasto[gastos.size()];`